# Buildozer displays error during deploying

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to deploy my Kivy app into Android using Buildozer, but it is throwing an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1041, in run_command
    targets = [x[0] for x in self.targets()]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1041, in <listcomp>
    targets = [x[0] for x in self.targets()]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 933, in targets
    fromlist=['buildozer'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 165
    sdk_root = f"--sdk_root={android_sdk_dir}"
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f-strings weren't introduced until Python 3.6.  That package should not have allowed itself to be installed in your 3.5 version.  You can fix this, if you're willing to edit that file, and change the line to

```
sdk_root = "--sdk_root=" + android_sdk_dir
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. I have one more error. It says "/bin/sh: 1: {sdkmanager_path}: not found
" How do you propose to solve it?

Comment: I propose that you debug it.  There are 5 or 6 other f-strings in that code, including one with `{sdkmanager_path}`.  All will have to be rewritten.  Alternatively, you could upgrade your Python.  3.5 is quite old.

Comment: I have replace them all. But the problem still persists.

Comment: If you had replaced them all, the problem would not still persist.  Perhaps you should post your new traceback.